# Restkit v0.20: how to create libRestkit.a file that will work on iphone/ipad simulator?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I ran restkit project and headers and librestkit.a were created in build products.i added that headers and libs restkit.a in my project and using .i can run my project on ipad / iphone device without any problems.When i run on iphone simulator. ipad simulator i get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the Debug-iphoneos folder to Debug-iphonesimulator and add renamed library (libRestKit-iphonesimulator.a) in it drag the folder in project with headers and use `#import "restkit .h"` to access it.